# Is there a way to mark and annotate special moments in a video?

Tags: video, video-editor

I have a long tutorial video, and it's easy for me to get lost. I really want to break the video down to parts by marking the beginning and end of each section. I also want to add a short summary to each part of the video. Is there any tool capable of doing these jobs?

vosaic.com has a browser based non-free tool, which is exactly what I want and looks like this:
[image]

However, I'm wondering if there is any open source free one available?

Comment: Take a look at this, it may help.


https://itsfoss.com/best-video-editing-software-linux/